# How to pass multiple strings between two different activities?

Tags: java, android, json, string, parsing

I am trying to pass multiple strings from MainActivity class parsed with json to SingleContactActivity class. Right now I am testing passing just the name and email strings, in logcat it says that the values were successfully passed but I cannot get both strings to output in SingleContactActivity. However if I try to pass the name string only it will output to SingleContactActivity. 
I removed imports for code clarity.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// URL to get contacts JSON
public static String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";

// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray contacts = null;

// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Listview on item click listener
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                    .getText().toString();
            String email = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email))
                    .getText().toString();

                            // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
            Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SingleContactActivity.class);

            // sending data to new activity
                in.putExtra("TAG_NAME", name);
            in.putExtra("TAG_EMAIL", email);

            startActivity(in);

        }
    });

    // Calling async task to get json
    new GetContacts().execute();
}
```

---

public class SingleContactActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       this.setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item_view);
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
       if( extras != null ) {
           String name = extras.getString("TAG_NAME");
           Log.d("", "Value passed = " + name);
           TextView txtContact = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
       txtContact.setText(name); 
               String email = extras.getString("TAG_EMAIL");
           Log.d("", "Value passed = " + email);
               TextView txtContact1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
           txtContact1.setText(email); 
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you pass json string to the second activity, retrieve it there and parse?

Comment: What happens if you only pass the email?

Comment: What about getIntent().getStringExtra() for your two strings?

Comment: @Gee858eeG : The `getStringExtra(...)` method is just a convenience method which effectively calls `getExtras().getString(...)`

Comment: I've been advised to pass the string instead of retrieving it again in the SingleListActivity since it is faster. Also, for some reason when I only pass the email the App just stops.

Comment: @user3192423 : I had a feeling you might say that about passing only the email. Check the resource id `R.id.email` is valid in your layout file - if it's not, you may be getting a `NullPointerException` on `txtContact1.setText(email);`. Post the logcat output showing what happens when only passing the email.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your `onCreate()` method :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
   if( intent != null ) {
       String name = intent.getStringExtra("TAG_NAME");
       Log.d("", "Value passed = " + name);
       TextView txtContact = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
       txtContact.setText(name); 
       String email = intent.getStringExtra("TAG_EMAIL");
       Log.d("", "Value passed = " + email);
       TextView txtContact1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
       txtContact1.setText(email); 
     }
```

Comment: The `getStringExtra(...)` method is just a convenience method which effectively calls `getExtras().getString(...)`

Comment: Change this in the MainActivity?

Comment: @user3192423 : This answer won't solve your problem - it's just another way of doing exactly what you're already doing.

Comment: @user3192423 nono, in the `SingleContactActivity`, but according to @Squonk comments, I'm not so confident about this. Let me know if it doesn't work!

Comment: @NariKimShin : Look at the source code for `Intent` and scroll down to line 4632 https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/Intent.java

Comment: @Squonk : yeap! You're right. It basically returns `mExtras.getString()`, so same thing!